# how do I correct this code to check for anagrams?

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings, anagram

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *a = "stack";
    char *b = "cats";
    int l = 0;  // for length of string b 
    clrscr();
    while (*b != NULL) 
        {
            l++;
            b++;
        }
    b--; // now b points to last char of the string 
    // printf("%d\n", l);
    while ((*a - *b == 32) || (*a == *b))
        {
            printf("%c %c\n", *a, *b);
            a++;
            b--;
            l--;
            if (l == 0)
                break;
        }
    l == 0 ? printf("anagrams") : printf("not anagrams");
    getch();
}
```

I wrote the code to check whether two strings a and b are anagrams.

the code displays a **false positive** when **b is shorter** in length than a and is a substring of a.

for eg. b is *"cats"* which in reverse is *"stac"* and a is *"stack"* the code shows a and b as anagrams

Comment: Check that they have the same strlen?

Comment: This isn't checking for anagrams, it's just checking for a substring, right? if the letters were in a different order it wouldn't work. Check for a difference in length, like kaylum said, then one trick you can use for anagrams is to sort both strings alphabetically, and then compare them. If they are anagrams they'll be equal.

Comment: The easy way to check for an anagram, is to use a pair of frequency arrays of the characters that make up the *subject* (e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` would require a 62-element array) and that appear in the proposed *anagram*. If the frequency array for the *subject* is equal to that of the proposed *anagram*, then you have an actual *anagram* After filling each frequency array, it is a simple matter of `if (memcmp (subfreq, anafreq, nelem * sizeof *subfreq) == 0) {...it's an anagram...}` This allows you to skip whitespace, etc.. e.g. `nag a ram` is an anagram of the subject word `anagram`.

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudo-code for checking if two strings are anagrams of each other (using your variable names):

```
if (strlen(a) != strlen(b))
    // Not an anagram
    return

char *a_sorted = sort_chars(a)
char *b_sorted = sort_chars(b)

// Once the characters in each word are re-arranged in alphabetical
// order, we can just test for equality. Anagrams will be equal
// (Note that this will not work on multi-word strings with differing
// numbers of whitespace characters)
if (strcmp(a_sorted, b_sorted) == 0)
    // Anagram!
else
    // Not an anagram
```

The real work here is in the `sort_chars(in)` function, which sorts the characters in the `in` string alphabetically, and returns a pointer to a new string containing the sorted characters. Using the numeric  ASCII values of the characters (they're already in alphabetical order, yay someone's doing something right out there!), something like [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (or any other sorting algorithm you want to use) should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you are writing looks more like you trying to check for the two words being palindromic. If that was your intent, you are taking the length of the smaller string, making `l` hit 0 before the last character of `a` is seen.

If you didn't want to check for palindromes, I would imagine that you are really looking for the code for checking if `a` is a permutation of `b`, since that code is the same as checking for an anagram if you just have one word.

**Don't do what others have suggested** and sort the strings and compare. That ranges from comparable to much worse than three, simple linear traversals, albeit with a small space trade-off and a bound on number of possible char occurrences in a string.

The logic is this: make a map from chars to occurrence values indicating what chars are present in `a` and how many times they occurred. Then, go through `b` once making sure that every char is present, decrementing the occurrence count. Then, go through b again, making sure all occurrences are zero.

Here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Only works for single words, but you get the idea.
int palindrome(const char* a, const char* b) {
    ssize_t len_a = (ssize_t)strlen(a);
    ssize_t len_b = (ssize_t)strlen(b);
    if (len_a != len_b) return 0;

    b += (len_b - 1);
    while (len_a--) if (*a++ != *b--) return 0;
    return 1;
}

 // Really checks for a case-sensitive permutations.
int anagram(const char* a, const char* b) {
    size_t len_a = strlen(a);
    size_t len_b = strlen(b);
    if (len_a != len_b) return 0;

    uint16_t occurrences[256] = {0};

    for (; *a; occurrences[(int)*a]++, a++);
    for (; *b; occurrences[(int)*b]--, b++) 
        if (!occurrences[(int)*b]) return 0;

    b -= len_b;
    for (; *b; b++) if (occurrences[(int)*b]) return 0;

    return 1;
}

 int main(void) {
    const char *a = "stack";
    const char *b = "kcats";
    printf("anagram: %d\n", anagram(a, b));

    b = "cats";
    printf("anagram: %d\n", anagram(a, b));

    b = "kcbts";
    printf("anagram: %d\n", anagram(a, b));

    a = "aabbcdddd";
    b = "aaddddbbc";
    printf("anagram: %d\n", anagram(a, b));

    a = "aabbcddcd";
    b = "aadddddbc";
    printf("anagram: %d\n", anagram(a, b));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that when you do any of these kinds of algorithms, there is an early trivial false condition if the lengths of the strings differ.

Also, the code is case-sensitive here for simplicity, but that is easily changed.

Output:

```
anagram: 1
anagram: 0
anagram: 0
anagram: 1
anagram: 0
```

Comment: An anagram doesn't just have the same letters, it also has the same occurrence count of *each letter*. It is a rearrangement in the purest sense. If you think checking lengths will ensure that, think again. You could have two words of the same length, but different multi-occurrence letters. Your code can account for *all* of this by being smarter with your counting array.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, you can use a simple *frequency array* (recording how many times each character of the *subject* appears) and do the same thing for the proposed *anagram* and then simply compare the two frequency arrays to determine if the *proposed anagram* is in fact an anagram of the *subject*.

For example, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXF 62

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *sub = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "anagram",
         *ana = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "nag a ram",
         *sp = sub, *ap = ana;

    int subf[MAXF] = {0},   /* subject frequency array */
        anaf[MAXF] = {0};   /* anagram frequency array */

    while (*sp) {   /* fill subject frequency array */
        if ('a' <= *sp && *sp <= 'z')
            subf[*sp - 'a']++;
        else if ('A' <= *sp && *sp <= 'Z')
            subf[*sp - 'A' + 26]++;
        else if ('0' <= *sp && *sp <= '9')
            subf[*sp - '0' + 52]++;
        sp++;
    }

    while (*ap) {   /* fill anagram frequency array */
        if ('a' <= *ap && *ap <= 'z')
            anaf[*ap - 'a']++;
        else if ('A' <= *ap && *ap <= 'Z')
            anaf[*ap - 'A' + 26]++;
        else if ('0' <= *ap && *ap <= '9')
            anaf[*ap - '0' + 52]++;
        ap++;
    }

    /* if character frequency arrays are equal - it's an anagram */
    if (memcmp (subf, anaf, MAXF * sizeof *subf) == 0)
        printf ("'%s' is an anagram of '%s'\n", ana, sub);
    else
        printf ("'%s' is NOT an anagram of '%s'\n", ana, sub);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Checking the default values of `anagram` and `nag a ram`

```
$ ./bin/anagram
'nag a ram' is an anagram of 'anagram'
```

Checking if `nag a rim` is an anagram of the subject word `anagram`

```
$ ./bin/anagram anagram "nag a rim"
'nag a rim' is NOT an anagram of 'anagram'
```